# Opening multiple files in perl array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a perl script where by I assigned all the files with a `.log` extension to an array called `@allfiles`. How do I run my script for the files stored in each array? My idea is something like `open(my $fn, '<', @allfiles) or die "Could not open file '@files': $!";` but that would be incorrect as it would read all files in the array at once. Any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX 'strftime';

#my $filename = 'IGXLEventLog.3.17.2015.20.25.12.625.log';
my $directory = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/otpms/Data";
my @allfiles = glob("*.log");
opendir (my $dir, $directory) or die "Could not open directory '$directory': $!";
open(my $fn, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

our @output;
my %details;

    captureData();

close ($fn);

my $timestamp = strftime '%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S', localtime;
@output = $timestamp .'.sql';
open(my $fh, '>', @output) or die "Could not create file '@output': $!";

    createFile();

close($fh);

sub captureData
{
    while(my $row = <$fn>)
    {
        chomp $row;

        if ($row =~ /Computer Name:\s*(\S+)/i ) # match computer name with white space then non white space
        {
            $details{tester_name} = $1;
        }
        elsif ($row =~ /Operating System:\s*(.*\S)/i ) # match operating system with white space then any word
        {
            $details{op_sys} = $1;
        }
        elsif ($row =~ /IG-XL Version:\s*([^;]*)/i ) # match ig-xl version with white space then semi colon
        {
            $details{igxl_vn} = $1;
        }
        elsif ($row =~ /^([\d.]+)\s+(\S+)(?=\s)/ ) #match slot with white space and then non white space
        {
            push @{$details{slot}}, $1;
            push @{$details{board_name}},  $2;
        }
    }
} # captureData

sub createFile
{
    my $log_time_stamp = (stat($filename))[9];
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime($log_time_stamp);
    my $nice_timestamp = sprintf ( "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
                                   $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec);
   print $nice_timestamp;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < @{$details{slot}}; $i++)
    {
    print {$fh}
        "INSERT INTO TesterDeviceMatrix.TBL_TESTER_INFO"
        ."(tester_name, operating_system, version, board_name, config , date_modified, log_created) "
        ."VALUES ('$details{tester_name}', '$details{op_sys}', '$details{board_name}[$i]', "
        ."'$details{igxl_vn}', '$details{slot}[$i]', '$timestamp', '$nice_timestamp');\n";
    }
} # createFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enclose the code that handles a single file in a loop that iterates over all of the log files

You should also reconsider the amount of comments that you use. It is far better to write your code and choose identifiers so that the behaviour is self-explanatory. It is also counter-productive to wrap parts of the process in subroutines

This is how I would implement your problem. I haven't been able to test except to the extent that it compiles

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use File::stat;
use Time::Piece;

use constant LOG_DIR => '/opt/lampp/htdocs/otpms/Data';
use constant COLUMNS => qw/ tester_name operating_system version board_name config date_modified log_created /;

my $now_timestamp = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S');
open my $out_fh, '>', "$now_timestamp.sql";

chdir LOG_DIR;

while ( my $logfile = glob '*.log' ) {

    warn "Processing $logfile\n";

    open my $log_fh, '<', $logfile;

    my %details;

    while ( <$log_fh> ) {

        if ( /Computer Name:\s*(\S+)/i ) {
            $details{tester_name} = $1;
        }
        elsif ( /Operating System:\s*(.*\S)/i ) {
            $details{op_sys} = $1;
        }
        elsif ( /IG-XL Version:\s*([^;]*)/i ) {
            $details{igxl_vn} = $1;
        }
        elsif ( /^([\d.]+)\s+(\S+)/ ) {
            push @{ $details{slot} }, $1;
            push @{ $details{board_name} }, $2;
        }
    }

    my $stat          = stat $logfile;
    my $log_timestamp = localtime($stat->mtime)->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#{ $details{slot} } ) {

        my @values = (
            $details{tester_name},
            $details{op_sys},
            $details{board_name}[$i],
            $details{igxl_vn},
            $details{slot}[$i],
            $now_timestamp,
            $log_timestamp,
        );

        printf {$out_fh} "INSERT INTO TesterDeviceMatrix.TBL_TESTER_INFO (%s) VALUES (%s);\n",
            join(', ', COLUMNS),
            join(', ', map "'$_'", @values);
    }
}

close $out_fh;
```

Comment: Hello Borodin. Yeah I understand the idea, just been finding a way to put it into use. I have a small problem with this though, Is `Time::Piece` a module? I'm not too sure but I don't think I have it on the server that I am using. It returns an error message saying `Can't locate Time/Piece.pm`.

Comment: @hzq: Yes it's been a core module since v5.10 of perl -- around eight years ago. It does sound like it's not on your server, so it's *really* due for an update

Comment: Hmm I just checked the version, it's 5.10.1 so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error message. Is there another way around this? I'm trying `POSIX 'strftime'` instead of it.

Comment: @hzq: It should definitely be there on 5.10.1. You should talk to system management

Comment: Don't think that's possible haha. I'll just use the way in my question. I have an error on `my $now_timestamp = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S');` saying `Can't locate object method "strftime" via package "Tue Jun 16 08:42:21 2015" (perhaps you forgot to load "Tue Jun 16 08:42:21 2015"?) at exTester.pl line 13.` If you would like, I could edit the question to show what I've done so far by integrating your answer.

Comment: I used `strftime` and got it working. However, there's one last problem. This doesn't actually create four files but it creates one file with all the statements inside. My goal is to create a new file for each existing log file. So if there were 6 log files there should be 6 new `.sql` extension files.

Comment: I realized this was an easier way. Thank you Borodin once again.